# Работа с SQLite в Android приложении

Tags: android

Салют всем местным. Пришел сюда с очередным вопросом.
В общем в есть интернет магазин,  в котором есть список: категорий, товаров, брендов, заказов. При запуске приложения я запрашиваю у сервера актуальные списки всего этого и сохраняю их в БД и при повторном открытии приложения эта процедура повторяеться и приложение падает по OutOfMemoryError.

в MainActivity я создаю базу данных и вызываю сервис что бы ее наполнить

```
DataSource dataSource = new DataSource(this);
startService(new Intent(this, DataBaseDownloadService.class));
```

В DataBaseDownloadService я обращаюсь к классам которые посылают запросы на сервер и возвращают мне списки, по которым я пробегаю циклом и добавляю каждый элемент в БД

```
 categoryList = categoryDAO.downloadCategories();
 productList = productDAO.downloadProducts();
 brandList = brandDAO.dowmloadBrands();
 orderList = orderDAO.downloadOrders();

    for (Category category : categoryList) {
        categoryDAO.addCategory(category);
    }

    for (Product product : productList) {
        productDAO.addProduct(product);
    }

    for (Brand brand : brandList) {
        brandDAO.addBrand(brand);
    }

    for (Order order : orderList) {
        orderDAO.addOrder(order);
    }
```

Вопрос:  каким образом можно организовать данный функционал, что  бы БД грузилась только при первом запуске приложения,  а при всех последующий запусках можно было подгружать к  примеру только обновленный список товаров?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. При запуске проверять есть ли хоть что-то в базе. Если да - не начинать закачку всего магазина.
2. Обновление можно организовать по разному. Например передав серверу кол-во загруженных элементов по категории из базы и грузить новые, если на сервере их больше. Какие грузить решить можно, например, по timestamp.

Comment: как можно проверить есть ли что то  в базе? как работает timestamp?
И как бысть со строкой DataSource dataSource = new DataSource(this); мне что бы проверить нужно создавать БД или можно как то по-другому?

Comment: Ну, сделать запрос и проверить сколько будет ответов... Если база вернёт 0 записей, то, видать, она пустая... timestamp - это временная метка. Часто отмечает время создания какой-либо записи. По ней удобно фильтровать списки от новых к старым. У обёрток над БД есть методы типа `getWritableDataBase()` возвращающих или создающих и возвращающих БД. А вообще если у вас ещё вопросы - создавайте новые. На ваш вопрос в нынешнем его виде сложно дать иной ответ, чем тот, что я уже написал.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!